# Select from upper level folder

Tags: php

So, I've created a website and I have lots of pages in the public_html folder. Those page load the images and script from folders who are direct child of public_html folder.

Now I need to move all those files into a folder (let's name it sample-folder).

My question: Is there any way to let the pages inside "sample-folder" access the images and scripts from other folders inside the "public_html" **without** having to edit all the pages and add a `../`images/image.png before each link?

I don't know, some htacces rewrite rule? Some php config.ini edit?

**Structure:**

```
public_html
     images
     scripts
     sample-folder
         test.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This .htaccess rule should work (assumes mod_rewrite is enabled):

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ sample-folder/images/$1
```

This would take all requests for files in the (non-existent) `images` directory and ask for the file in `sample-folder/images/` instead.

Hope this is what you were after.

**EDIT**: My mistake, read the question wrong. Just do this for your paths and the .php files will reference the images correctly no matter how deep in the directory the .php file is:

`<img src="/images/myimage.jpg" />`

You can use the `../relative/path` approach, bit the `/leading/forward/slash/approach.jpg` should work all the time.

**EDIT**: If changing the links is not an option for you, you can put this .htaccess file in `sample-folder`. It will route all requests from within `sample-folder` for `images` to `/images` in the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /images/$1
```

Make sure it goes in `sample-folder` or whatever you choose to name it.

---

Keep in mind that this is NOT the best solution. If you start abusing rewrite rules now, your application is going to be a confusing mess very quickly. Typically, I would set a constant, variable, or *write a php function* that resolves your URLs and/or include paths.

For includes: please see [set_include_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

This should ensure that your php includes get called from the same place no matter where you are in the directory tree. Typically, this would be set in some sort of bootstrap file or any file that is included at the top of all your scripts.

For images, javascript, etc - I highly suggest changing ALL your paths to use the leading forward slash or an absolute URL (preferably in a constant or function call). You're already seeing why writing functions for simple tasks that you do often (like referencing an image in HTML) is a good idea.

It might seem like a pain now to change all these files, but rest assured that this is going to save you **loads** of headache later. I suggest something similar to this:

- Download your whole application locally
- Make a backup
- Find a [text editor that supports find/replace in files](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
- Fix all the paths to images, javascript, css, etc. to use the leading forward slash for now
- Consider utilizing your own php functions from now on, that will save you the effort of *ever* having to do anything like this again

Comment: I've already used "images/myimage.jpg" and I can't add a "/" before all the links...

Comment: You can't you add a forward slash? Have you considered doing a global search and replace in all files with your text editor?

Comment: @Cristy: Try the edit I posted and see if that works, I didn't test it.

Comment: Cristy: The changes *should* show up immediately. If you want to check, paste a bunch of nonsense in the .htaccess and see if you get an internal server error 500.

Comment: Oh, and even with the "/" seems the links don't work. They only work using "../"

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page so I can see?

Comment: Yes, i get the error, but it seems like it doesn't work... I tried even a rewrite rule to remove the ".php" ending but still nothing

Comment: Oh, they work, my bad. Didn't see that I had to place the .htacces in that folder. Now, can I resolve that includes?

Comment: Cristy, all these folks have taken time to help, with good answers, and you haven't given anyone a **single** vote? And now you're changing your question? What's going on here?

Comment: I will be giving votes after I'll solve my problem. Now, I really want to make that work... And the question was how to do it for a general folder, not only for images.

Comment: The problem is that you're asking for a specific solution, that you already decided was the best one (which it isn't). Include paths and http requests are two separate things. Give me a minute to go make some coffee and I'll come back and help you out a bit.

Answer (score 2):

If they are in a structure like this (from what it sounds like they are):

```
/ (document root)
    /images
    /scripts
    /sample-folder
        /test.php
```

Then you should be able to access an image by `../images/filename.png` and `/images/filename.png`. Referring to the document root is an easier option than managing different levels of directory structure.

Comment: If I use "images/filename.png" the images don't load.

Comment: Prefix it with a forward-slash (e.g. `<img src="/images/filename.png">` - this indicates it is relevant to the web root.

Comment: That's the problem. I have thousand of links that don't have that slash and I can't edit them all...

Comment: Well if they can't be replaced using an editor or grep in one go then yeah use a rewrite rule as Wesley suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If your images and scripts are in a specific folder that's not changing.  Simply make your links to them be absolute instead of relative.

Comment: The idea is that I can't change the links.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from `/sample-folder/images/` to `/images/`. [How to create a symbolic link in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php). Though personally I would just do a Find/Replace to update the links in your source code.

Comment: @Cristy: Windows supports symbolic links. What version of windows is the server running? What type of access do you have to it (remote desktop/it's right in front of you/only ftp)?

Comment: from a console run `ln -s /path/images /path/sample-folder/images`